# Retain Max Value of Vector until vector Catches up

Tags: r, time-series

I have some cumulative count data.  Because of reporting innacuracies, sometimes the cumulative sum decreases such as `0 1 2 2 3 3 2 4 5`.

I would like to created a new vector that retains the largest value reported and carries it forward until the cumulative count data catches up. So the corrected version of the above would be `0 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5`

I tried the following

```
mydf <- data.frame(ts1 = c(0,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,3,4,4,5))
mydf$lag1 <- lag(mydf[,1])
mydf$corrected <- ifelse(is.na(mydf[,2]),mydf[,1],
                         ifelse(mydf[,2] > mydf[,1], mydf[,2], mydf[,1]))
```

which returns:

```
   ts1 lag1 corrected
1    0   NA         0
2    1    0         1
3    1    1         1
4    1    1         1
5    2    1         2
6    3    2         3
7    2    3         3
8    2    2         2
9    3    2         3
10   4    3         4
11   4    4         4
12   5    4         5
```

This worked for the case of the first time that the next value was smaller than the previous value(line7) but it fails for the second time(line 8).

I thought there must be a better way of doing this.  New Vector that is equal to input vector unless value decreases in which case it retains prior value until input vector exceeds that retained value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `cummax` :

```
cummax(mydf$ts1)
#[1] 0 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew this logic had to have been worked into a function.